contact form using nextjs emailjs react-hook-form and react-toastify
I am trying to build a contact form, but it isn't working, the validation is fine but the emailjs implementation is not working the input doesn't show the data  the console got some errors but nothing related to this, I use what I found in some tutorials but I'm not sure how to implement this package, can anybody help me?
'use client';

import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const ContactForm = () => {
  const formRef = useRef();
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    subject: '',
    message: '',
  });

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    setForm(data);
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        formRef.current,
        {
          from_name: form.name,
          to_name: 'Sophie',
          from_email: form.email,
          to_email: process.env.EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY,
          phone: form.phone,
          subject: form.subject,
          message: form.message,
        },
        process.env.EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY
      )
      .then(() => {
        toast.success('Email sent successfully');
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error(error.text);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className=' bg-dark-900 rounded-3xl'>
      <form
        ref={formRef}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className='flex flex-col space-y-4 py-10 px-8'
      >
        <ToastContainer />
        <fieldset>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='name'
            value={form.name}
            placeholder='Name'
            {...register('name', { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.name && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input
            type='email'
            name='email'
            value={form.email}
            placeholder='Email'
            {...register('email', { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.email && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input
            type='tel'
            name='phone'
            value={form.phone}
            placeholder='Phone'
            {...register('phone', { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.phone && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <input
            type='text'
            name='subject'
            value={form.subject}
            placeholder='Subject'
            {...register('subject', { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.subject && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <textarea
            name='message'
            value={form.message}
            row={3}
            placeholder='Message'
            {...register('message', { required: true })}
          />
          {errors.message && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </fieldset>
        <button
          type='submit'
          className='btn'
          disabled={isLoading}
        >
          {isLoading ? 'Sending...' : 'Send'}
        </button>
        
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;

I want to send a contact email but the form is not working at all

Hooks are updated in the next cycle. Use "data" for your case.
